# Performance issues when cropping UIImage (CoreGraphics, iOS)

Tags: ios, uikit, uiimage, core-graphics, crop

The basic idea of what we are trying to do is that we have a large UIImage, and we want to slice it into several pieces. The user of the function can pass in a number of rows and number of columns, and the image will be cropped accordingly (ie. 3 rows and 3 columns slices the image into 9 pieces).  The problem is, we're having performance issues when trying to accomplish this with CoreGraphics.  The largest grid we require is 5x5, and it takes several seconds for the operation to complete (which registeres as lagtime to the user.)  This is of course far from optimal.

My colleague and I have spent quite a while on this, and have searched the web for answers unsuccessfully.  Neither of us are extremely experienced with Core Graphics, so I'm hoping there's some silly mistake in the code that will fix our problems.  It's left to you, SO users, to please help us figure it out!

We used the tutorial at http://www.hive05.com/2008/11/crop-an-image-using-the-iphone-sdk/ to base revisions of our code on.

The function below:

```
-(void) getImagesFromImage:(UIImage*)image withRow:(NSInteger)rows withColumn:(NSInteger)columns
{
    CGSize imageSize = image.size;
    CGFloat xPos = 0.0;
    CGFloat yPos = 0.0;
    CGFloat width = imageSize.width / columns;
    CGFloat height = imageSize.height / rows;

    int imageCounter = 0;

    //create a context to do our clipping in
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(width, height));
    CGContextRef currentContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGRect clippedRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height);
    CGContextClipToRect(currentContext, clippedRect);

    for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        xPos = 0.0;
        for(int j = 0; j < columns; j++)
        {
            //create a rect with the size we want to crop the image to
            //the X and Y here are zero so we start at the beginning of our
            //newly created context
            CGRect rect = CGRectMake(xPos, yPos, width, height);

            //create a rect equivalent to the full size of the image
            //offset the rect by the X and Y we want to start the crop
            //from in order to cut off anything before them
            CGRect drawRect = CGRectMake(rect.origin.x * -1,
                                     rect.origin.y * -1,
                                     image.size.width,
                                     image.size.height);

            //draw the image to our clipped context using our offset rect
            CGContextDrawImage(currentContext, drawRect, image.CGImage);

            //pull the image from our cropped context
            UIImage* croppedImg = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();


            //PuzzlePiece is a UIView subclass
            PuzzlePiece* newPP = [[PuzzlePiece alloc] initWithImageAndFrameAndID:croppedImg :rect :imageCounter];
            [slicedImages addObject:newPP];

            imageCounter++;
            xPos += (width);
        }
        yPos += (height);
    }
    //pop the context to get back to the default
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
}
```

ANY advice greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Are you saving the images somewhere or only showing them to the user in 5x5 different views on screen? If you are only showing them it will probably be more efficient to set the entire image in every view (it's still only one image in memory) and then offset it for each UIImageView so that only the correct part is visible in each view.

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist We're only displaying them, not saving them. Your answer sounds like a much more efficient solution! I've never tried offsetting a UIImage within a UIImageView--I've only used initWithImage and setImage to set the image itself, never played with it afterward. How do you do that? Though I suppose--I could use a regular UIView with clipsToBounds = true, add a UIImageView as a subview, and offset that UIImageView by whatever amount was necessary?

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist My variation of what you suggested--with the UIView/clipsToBounds/UIImageView as subview--worked like a charm!  If you post an answer detailing that along with your original suggestion, I'd be happy to accept it :)  Thanks so much--this has so been bugging me!!

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist - I wouldn't be so sure that you've only got one copy of the image in memory. Each one of those views should hold a separate uncompressed version of the image (4 bytes per pixel) behind the scenes, which I think you'll see if you look at the true size of the application in the Memory Monitor instrument.

Comment: @BradLarson Hmm, in that case this certainly isn't a memory-efficient solution.  Do you have any ideas for something we can do that doesn't use up a lot of memory and also runs efficiently?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

originalImageView is an IBOutlet ImageView. This image will be cropped.

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

QuartzCore is needed for the white border around each slice for better understanding.

```
-(UIImage*)getCropImage:(CGRect)cropRect
{
CGImageRef image = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([originalImageView.image CGImage],cropRect);
UIImage *cropedImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:image];
CGImageRelease(image);
return cropedImage;
}

-(void)prepareSlices:(uint)row:(uint)col
{
float flagX = originalImageView.image.size.width / originalImageView.frame.size.width;
float flagY = originalImageView.image.size.height / originalImageView.frame.size.height;

float _width    = originalImageView.frame.size.width / col;
float _height   = originalImageView.frame.size.height / row;

float _posX = 0.0;
float _posY = 0.0;

for (int i = 1; i <= row * col; i++) {

    UIImageView *croppedImageVeiw = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(_posX, _posY, _width, _height)];
    UIImage *img = [self getCropImage:CGRectMake(_posX * flagX,_posY * flagY, _width * flagX, _height * flagY)];
    croppedImageVeiw.image = img;

    croppedImageVeiw.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor];
    croppedImageVeiw.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;

    [self.view addSubview:croppedImageVeiw];
    [croppedImageVeiw release];

    _posX += _width;

    if (i % col == 0) {
        _posX = 0;
        _posY += _height;
    }

}

originalImageView.alpha = 0.0;

}
```

originalImageView.alpha = 0.0; you won't see the originalImageView any more.

Call it like this:

```
[self prepareSlices:4 :4];
```

It should make 16 slices addSubView on self.view. We have a puzzle app. This is working code from there.

Comment: I got everything working with David Rönnqvist's comment above, but this seems like it would work as well.  If I get a chance to go back and play with that code, I'll give this a try.  Thanks!