# my image is not getting cropped

Tags: ios, uiimage

i have the following code that i mostly got from SO but my image still is not getting cropped, what am i doing wrong?

```
@synthesize TopImage;
@synthesize BottomImage;
@synthesize RotaterImage;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
if (self) {
    TopImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"zero.png"];
    [TopImage drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(0, 0)];
    [self cropImage:TopImage:0];
    [self addSubview:[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:TopImage]];
//        BottomImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"zero.png"];
//        [BottomImage drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(0, 55)];
//        [self cropImage:BottomImage:50];
//        [self addSubview:[[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:BottomImage]retain]];
//        RotaterImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"zero.png"];
//        [RotaterImage drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(0, 0) blendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:0];
//        [self addSubview:[[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:RotaterImage]retain]];
//        [self cropImage:RotaterImage:50];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)cropImage:(UIImage *)image:(int)startCroppingPosition{
  CGRect tempRect = CGRectMake(0, startCroppingPosition, 23, 40);
  CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([image CGImage], tempRect);
  // or use the UIImage wherever you like
  image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef]; 
  CGImageRelease(imageRef);
}
```

I am very new to IOS so any help is appreciated

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10868876/1378447

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're creating a new cropped image but not telling the `init` method about it :)

Try this change :

```
-(UIImage *)cropImage:(UIImage *)image:(int)startCroppingPosition{
  CGRect tempRect = CGRectMake(0, startCroppingPosition, 23, 40);
  CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([image CGImage], tempRect);
  // or use the UIImage wherever you like
  UIImage *newImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef]; 
  CGImageRelease(imageRef);
  return newImage;
}
```

and, in `init`, replace

```
[TopImage drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(0, 0)];
```

with

```
UIImageView* topImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:topImage];
topImageView.frame = CGRectMake(x,y,width,height);
```

Your crop method now returns the newly cropped image and stores it in `TopImage`.

---

Other advice :

Class names begin with a CapitalLetter, variables begin with lowercase. `TopImage` should really be `topImage`.

Also, I would always use named parameters in your methods, so

```
-(void)cropImage:(UIImage *)image:(int)startCroppingPosition
```

should be something like

```
-(void)cropImage:(UIImage *)image startPosition:(int)startCroppingPosition
```

That will make your code much much more readable when you come back to it in a month's time (I've learned that the hard way in the past!)

Comment: drawAtPoint doesn't return anything but returning the image from the cropImage function did show the cropped image. What I don't understand is why can't i just set the image to the new cropped one like image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];??

Comment: You're only setting the `image` pointer inside your method to point to your new image. You're not affecting the `TopImage` pointer in your `init` method at all, that will still point to the old `UIImage`. If you wanted to affect the `TopImage` pointer from within the cropImage method you would either need to pass a pointer to the pointer or set `TopImage` directly inside `cropImage`. However, pointer to pointer is tricky and setting `TopImage` won't let you use `cropImage` to crop anything else. I'd return a new image and deal with updating where `TopImage` points to in your `init` method

Comment: huh i thought UIImage* was a pointer and that setting the new image to it would just mean using an equals operator. so i'd have to do UIImage** and then do *image?

Comment: That's right :) `UIImage*` is a pointer but when you pass it like that into another method you're passing a _copy_ of that pointer - a new variable (in your case called `image`) that points to the same `UIImage` object. Passing in `UIImage **` would give you a pointer to the original pointer (`TopImage`) so yes, then you'd do `*image = ...`

Answer (score 0):

You are only changing the image and not the image of the UIImageView,

What I would do is replace:

```
[self addSubview:[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:TopImage]];
```

with

```
UIImageView *iv = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:TopImage]];
iv.tag = 1000 //number does not matter 
[self.view addSubview:iv];
[iv release];
```

then in crop image you just add:

```
UIImageView *iv = [self.vief viewWithTag:1000];
iv.image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
```

This should then work as expected!

Comment: Same answer as me but I would return the new image from the `cropImage` method so, if needed, `cropImage` can be reused for other images (like `BottomImage` or `RotaterImage` :)